# Electron defaultConfig doesn't have an "app" parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, electron, es6-promise

I'm trying to fix an error that doesn't appear for other people trying to run this project. When running, I get this error:

`The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object`

from the lines

```
const isoPath = electronSettings.get("settings.isoPath");
const fileDir = path.dirname(isoPath);
```

It turns out that `isoPath` is an uncaught typeerror promise object that basically says the following:

`Cannot read property "app" of undefined`

Going further into the code, I discovered this:

It's trying to get `e.app`, but `e` is undefined because `return (_a = config.electron) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : electron_1.default;` evaluates to true, which means that either `_a === void 0` or `(_a = config.electron) === null` and since `_a` is undefined, we can assume `_a === void 0`, so for some reason `config.electron` has been defined but not given a value - `config` is defined by `__assign({}, defaultConfig);`.

`defaultConfig`:

```
var defaultConfig = {
    atomicSave: true,
    fileName: 'settings.json',
    numSpaces: 2,
    prettify: false,
};
```

There is no `settings.json` in my `node_modules/` which relates to electron-settings at all, which I believe may be the source of my problems but I don't see anyone online discussing this issue.

For the curious, the problem file is at `node_modules/electron-settings/dist/settings.js:92:70`, in the function `getElectronApp`.

Note that I'm on WSL1, though it shouldn't affect much in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what fixed this, but recloning the repo I was working with and running everything from windows instead of WSL did the trick.